# CoffeeScript + Angular Implicit Return in Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I have an angular app using ngRoute when I declare controller normally it doesn't work correctly becault of implicit return of coffeescript so I use this [solution](http://thejsguy.com/javascript/angular.js/coffeescript/2014/12/29/angular-coffeescript.html) but this time I get this error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'BarsController' is not a function, got undefined
```

simplified version of myApp:

```
angule.module('app',['ngRoute'])
.config(($routeProvider)->
  $routeProvider.when('/bar',
    templateUrl:'bar/bars.html'
    controller:'BarsController'
    controllerAs:'bc'
  )
)
angular.module('app').controller('BarsController',['$scope','$resource',BarsCtrl])
class BarsCtrl
  constructor:($scope,$resource)->
    console.log "in controller"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the same link you provide, it suggests to put the controller definition last:

```
angule.module('app',['ngRoute'])
.config(($routeProvider)->
  $routeProvider.when('/bar',
    templateUrl:'bar/bars.html'
    controller:'BarsController'
    controllerAs:'bc'
  )
)

class BarsCtrl
  constructor:($scope,$resource)->
    console.log "in controller"

angular.module('app').controller('BarsController',['$scope','$resource',BarsCtrl])
```